# jQuery mobile - Panels with multiple internal pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to be able to use a sliding panel, and when the user selects an option from within the sliding panel, it to load a new page found internally within same html file. So far, I have this:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
          $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#Home");;
      }); 
      function navigate(page){
          //$.mobile.changePage("#" + page);
          $("body").pagecontainer("change", "#" + page);
      }
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>

      <div data-role="page" id="Bio">
        <div data-role="panel" id="bioPanel"> 
          <ul id="menu">
            <li onclick="navigate('Bio')">Bio</li>
            <li onclick="navigate('Media')">Media</li>
            <li onclick="navigate('Booking')">Booking</li>
          </ul>
        </div> 

        <div data-role="header">
          <h1>My Site</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
          <p>Biography</p>
          <a href="#bioPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
          <h1>My Site</h1>
        </div> 
      </div> 

      <div data-role="page" id="Media">
        <div data-role="panel" id="mediaPanel"> 
          <ul id="menu">
            <li onclick="navigate('Bio')">Bio</li>
            <li onclick="navigate('Media')">Media</li>
            <li onclick="navigate('Booking')">Booking</li>
          </ul>
        </div> 

        <div data-role="header">
          <h1>My Site</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
          <p>Media</p>
          <a href="#mediaPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
          <h1>My Site</h1>
        </div> 
      </div>

      <div data-role="page" id="Booking">
        <div data-role="panel" id="bookingPanel"> 
          <ul id="menu">
            <li onclick="navigate('Bio')">Bio</li>
            <li onclick="navigate('Media')">Media</li>
            <li onclick="navigate('Booking')">Booking</li>
          </ul>
        </div> 

        <div data-role="header">
          <h1>My Site</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
          <p>Booking</p>
          <a href="#bookingPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
          <h1>My Site</h1>
        </div> 
      </div>

      </body>
      </html>
```

This code works, but as you'll notice I have to include the slide menu in each iteration. I'd like to be able to write the panel portion just once and have it open on each page. Is that possible?

I've already tried jQuery.load() and for some reason it won't work, despite it being on the same server so there shouldn't be a cross-domain issue. It could be an issue with the GoDaddy server I'm using, but I can't be sure.

I'd like to be able to do the same thing with the header and footer too, as they won't be changing across pages either.

Comment: You can use an external panel: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/

Comment: That worked, with some doing. I'll add my code to do it, but you should put this as an answer so you can get credit.

Comment: you can add one div with panel and append that with each page

Answer (score 1):

You can use an external panel for this: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/

Pull your panel out of the individual pages and place it as a child of the body element.  Make sure you apply a data-theme to it, as it has no container to inherit themes from.

```
<div data-role="panel" id="bioPanel" data-theme="a">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#Bio">Bio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Media">Media</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Booking">Booking</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then on document ready, initialize the widget as a panel and also initialize the listview within it:

```
$(function () {
    $("body>[data-role='panel']").panel().find("ul").listview();
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8uq72ohn/)**

Comment: instead of the `.find("ul").listview()` you can use `.enhanceWithin()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external panel:

[Jquery Mobile External panel demo](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/)