# issue with panel data-display push

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm just getting into jQuery Mobile - loving it but now hitting the learning curve. Basically I want a number of pages that call the same panel. I have the following. Most of it works. However every other "push" fails with the panel content disparaging at the end of the push ... can't see why.

page1.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("panel.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">

  <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" data-display="push"> 
    <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </div> 


  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Header</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>Click on the button below to open the Panel.</p>
    <a href="#myPanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Open Panel</a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Page Footer</h1>
  </div> 
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

calls panel.html ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h2>List with data-inset="true":</h2>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">List Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

would appreciate your comments
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use external panels: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/

See similar question: [jQuery mobile - Panels with multiple internal pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920240/jquery-mobile-panels-with-multiple-internal-pages/28928752#28928752)

If you really want to load an external html panel, you should use the jQM pagecreate event of each page and have unique IDs for each panel on each page. Also, on load complete you should enhance the panel widget.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone", function(){ 
    $("#includedContent").load( "panel.html", function() {
        $(this).closest('[data-role="panel"]').enhanceWithin();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi & thanks for your response (this is why I included the newbie warning :) I note your wording "if you really want to load ..." my question is "why wouldn't I?" I want the same panel on every page to give a consistent means of navigation across all pages, so only having 1 page to maintain makes sense right?

Comment: @giles, External Panels accomplishes the same thing, except you include the markup once within the main page body dom element, see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8uq72ohn/.  The common panel is only included once within the DOM at runtime. In yours, you are creating an empty container in each page, so you have to manage ID uniqueness, all loading, and making sure the jQM widgets are properly initialized/enhanced. After visiting several pages, you will end up with the same panel DOM elements duplicated in each page.  Either way will work, just choose what is best for your application.